# What are these autogenerated Db files?

Tags: database, grails

I'm developing a grails app that uses reentrant locking and database locking.  I just noticed some additional files that were autogenerated.  I am wondering what they are.  They are called:

```
devDb.h2.db
devDb.lock.db
devDb.trace.db
```

There is also a set for test configuration:

```
testDb.h2.db
testDb.trace.db
```

I am assumming that *Db.h2.db is just my database (set to be a file rather than in memory in my DataSource.groovy).  But what about the other ones?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `devDb.h2.db` is the database itself. ( `devDb.mv.db` for the newer version )
- `devDb.lock.db` is a lock file.  H2 allows multiple processes to share the database and this file is used to coordinate access.  When the database shuts down cleanly, this file should be removed automatically.
- `devDb.trace.db` is just a log for inspecting or debugging H2.  Whether or not it's created and how much detail gets logged can be controlled by adding a `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE` parameter to the JDBC URL.
- `testDb.h2.db` and `testDb.trace.db` are the same as the `devDb` counterparts that are used in the test environment (e.g. `grails test-app`).

Comment: I am using grails and IntelliJ, I am just stopping the process in the IDE.  Is it possible I am not shutting down the DB at all?  What do you do to shut down the DB?

Comment: The DB will automatically get closed when the VM exits on a shutdown hook.  That doesn't happen when running in IntelliJ, but it's harmless when the database isn't being shared by multiple processes.

Comment: @ataylor "trace.db" is for trace, but I want to know when this file is created, at the time of connecting with the database it is not created but after some days it automatically got created.